# CSS Coin flip animation issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I got a coin flip CSS animation from `[https://www.html5andbeyond.com/coin-flip-application-html-css-and-jquery][1]` but its not working on my page. I tried to confirm by checking on fiddle but its not working there also. However, its working on the provider's website. Here is the fiddle link I created to check. [`https://jsfiddle.net/7q8dqfxy/`](https://jsfiddle.net/7q8dqfxy/)

Codes are placed as it is on fiddle. Please check for the issue and help me guys.

Comment: Include the jQuery framework in your Fiddle (click the javascript/cogwheel) https://jsfiddle.net/7q8dqfxy/3/

Comment: If you using jQuery you have to include the library, as soon as this is the case it works (at least in the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7q8dqfxy/4/)

Comment: Its working @Goombah in fiddle... where did you change ?

Comment: @ShubhamJha You can click the cog wheel in the JavaScript frame.

Answer (score 1):

The JavaScript code here relies on the jQuery library, so you need to include that as an external resource.

In jsFiddle, this can be achieved like this:

[image: jsfiddle]

In your regular page, you'll want to either bundle jQuery with your HTML page, or include a link via a [CDN](https://code.jquery.com/) like this

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why this answer got downvoted? He is right. Just add jquery:
https://jsfiddle.net/ju2exx29/

Comment: Most probably since the comments were sufficient and were there before this answer. So this answer may seem like a bit of a cheap shot for easy reputation points. Not my downvote though.

Comment: @Goombah I honestly didn't see that comments had been added as I was typing the answer in the answer box down below.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery library is missing.

Insert below line in your code

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/aq0kw4Lq/